# jQuery adjacent siblings selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a card game with 13 sibling images with id="img1" through id="img13". (only the image source is different.

The images are position: absolute, they are tiled and slightly overlapping horizontally.

[image: 13 cards:]

When user clicks a card I make it grow and translate up like above.

Now my question is: what is the best way to select 1 card to the left and 1 card to the right to make them grow to an intermediate size, thus creating a wave effect?

Caveat: When the leftmost cad is selected, no card to the left, and same for the rightmost card: no card to the right.

Comment: Us if length > 0 for left and right end cards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all the `img` elements are siblings, you can use `next()` and `prev()` to get the previous/next sibling elements. Something like this:

```
$('.img').click(function() {
    $('.img').removeClass('current sibling');
    $(this).addClass('current').prev().addClass('sibling');
    $(this).next().addClass('sibling');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pzjAG/)

Comment: Thanks! Neat, concise and elegant solution.